# How can I create a ViewModel that accesses data from a Room database without invoking a RuntimeException?

Tags: java, android, database, viewmodel

I have created a Room databsae with Entities, DAOs, a Database and a ViewModel. I seem to be having an issue with the ViewModel crashing my app on startup with two errors: a `java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.whatamidoingwithmylife.splitbill.RestaurantViewModel` and a `java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.whatamidoingwithmylife.splitbill.RestaurantViewModel`.

Here is the full stack trace:

`07-05 20:35:57.244 23174-23174/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.whatamidoingwithmylife.splitbill, PID: 23174
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.whatamidoingwithmylife.splitbill/com.whatamidoingwithmylife.splitbill.SBSplash}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.whatamidoingwithmylife.splitbill.RestaurantViewModel
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2684)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1496)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.whatamidoingwithmylife.splitbill.RestaurantViewModel
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:205)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:133)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:101)
        at com.whatamidoingwithmylife.splitbill.SBSplash.onCreate(SBSplash.java:28)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6684)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2637)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1496) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:197)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:133) 
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:101) 
        at com.whatamidoingwithmylife.splitbill.SBSplash.onCreate(SBSplash.java:28) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6684) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2637) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1496) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
        at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotMainThread(RoomDatabase.java:164)
        at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:192)
        at com.whatamidoingwithmylife.splitbill.RestaurantDao_Impl.getAllRestaurants(RestaurantDao_Impl.java:77)
        at com.whatamidoingwithmylife.splitbill.RestaurantRepository.<init>(RestaurantRepository.java:16)
        at com.whatamidoingwithmylife.splitbill.RestaurantViewModel.<init>(RestaurantViewModel.java:15)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:197) 
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:133) 
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:101) 
        at com.whatamidoingwithmylife.splitbill.SBSplash.onCreate(SBSplash.java:28) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6684) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2637) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1496) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)`

Here is `SBSplash.java`'s `onCreate` method:

```
private RestaurantViewModel mRestaurantViewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sbsplash);

    RecyclerView anotherOne = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_id);
    final RestaurantListAdapter adapter = new RestaurantListAdapter(this);
    anotherOne.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2));
    anotherOne.setAdapter(adapter);

    mRestaurantViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(RestaurantViewModel.class);
}
```

Here is `RestaurantRepository.java`:

```
private RestaurantDao mRestaurantDao;
private List<Restaurant> mAllRestaurants;

RestaurantRepository(Application application) {
    SplitBillRoomDatabase db = SplitBillRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);
    mRestaurantDao = db.restaurantDao();
    mAllRestaurants = mRestaurantDao.getAllRestaurants();
}

List<Restaurant> getAllRestaurants() {
    return mAllRestaurants;
}

public void insert(Restaurant restaurant) {
    new insertAsyncTask(mRestaurantDao).execute(restaurant);
}

private static class insertAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Restaurant, Void, Void> {

    private RestaurantDao mAsyncTaskDao;

    insertAsyncTask(RestaurantDao dao) {
        mAsyncTaskDao = dao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final Restaurant... params) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Here is `RestaurantViewModel.java`:

```
private RestaurantRepository mRepository;
private List<Restaurant> mAllRestaurants;

public RestaurantViewModel(Application application) {
    super(application);
    mRepository = new RestaurantRepository(application);
    mAllRestaurants = mRepository.getAllRestaurants();
}

List<Restaurant> getAllRestaurants() {
    return mAllRestaurants;
}

public void insert(Restaurant restaurant) {
    mRepository.insert(restaurant);
}
```

Here is `RestaurantDao.java`:

`@Dao
public interface RestaurantDao {`

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Restaurants")
List<Restaurant> getAllRestaurants();

@Insert
void insert(Restaurant restaurant);

@Query("DELETE FROM Restaurants")
void deleteAll();
```

`}`

Edit: Here is `Restaurant.java`:

```
package com.whatamidoingwithmylife.splitbill;

import android.arch.persistence.room.ColumnInfo;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Entity;
import android.arch.persistence.room.PrimaryKey;

@Entity(tableName = "Restaurants")
public class Restaurant {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int ResID;

@ColumnInfo(name = "ResName")
private String Name;

@ColumnInfo(name = "ResPicture")
private int PictureID;

public Restaurant(String Name, int PictureID) {
    this.Name = Name;
    this.PictureID = PictureID;
}

public int getPictureID() {
    return PictureID;
}

public void setPictureID(int pictureID) {
    PictureID = pictureID;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public int getResID() {
    return ResID;
}

public void setResID(int resID) {
    ResID = resID;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}
```

}

Comment: Is the RestaurantViewModel class public?

Comment: Yes, it is public.

Comment: can you post the Restaurant class

Comment: Certainly. I've edited the main post.

Comment: what does RestaurantViewModel.java extends?

Comment: It extends `AndroidViewModel`

Comment: what does SBSplash.java extend?

Comment: make sure dependencies are all the same version

Comment: SBSplash extends AppCompatActivity. I'll have a look at all the dependencies in a second.

Comment: Updated all the dependencies to the same version, still crashing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm fixed it

Okay, jokes aside, I fixed it by implementing `LiveData` around all of the `java.util.List`s that I used. Somehow that fixed it, I'm not going to ask any further questions as to why it worked, it just worked and I'm glad it worked. Thanks for all your help.